# What is local retention in programming ? Reference to Alan Kay quote

Tags: oop, object

Alan Kay [said](http://userpage.fu-berlin.de/~ram/pub/pub_jf47ht81Ht/doc_kay_oop_en)

> OOP to me means only messaging, local retention and protection and
>
> hiding of state-process, and extreme late-binding of all things.

What is local retention? Can someone explain with an example from any programming language (e.g. Java,Scala, Lisp, Haskell)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To parse the sentence correctly, "OOP to me means only

- messaging
- (local retention, protection, and hiding) of state-process
- extreme late-binding of all things
  "

So I think "local retention ... of state-process" just means that state is kept locally within objects.

Comment: Local retention, protection, and hiding are properties of encapsulation.  But, to be clear, **not** necessarily data-bags & accessors.